# Merge classes with JSS instead of overriding

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jss

I'm using React and JSS to try to build a small set of reusable components, but I'm running into issues trying to compose base components into more complex ones.

When I pass class names down from a parent component via the `classes` prop, it completely overrides the default styles instead of merging them. See the snippet below for a demonstration: when wrapped, the text input looses the border styles and only takes on the width specified in the wrapper.

```js
const { Component } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM;
const injectSheet = reactJss.default;

// TextInput.jsx
const TextInput = (() => {
  const styles = {
    root: {
      border: '1px solid #ccc',
      borderRadius: 3,
    }
  };
  const TextInput = ({ classes, ...rest }) => (
    <input className={classes.root} type="text" {...rest} />
  );
  return injectSheet(styles)(TextInput);
})();

// InputField.jsx
const InputField = (() => {
  const styles = {
    root: {
      display: 'inline-flex',
    },
    label: {
      marginRight: 5,
      width: 40,
    },
    input: {
      width: 80,
    },
  };
  const InputField = ({ classes, id, label }) => (
    <span className={classes.root}>
      <label className={classes.label} htmlFor={id}>{label}</label>
      <TextInput classes={{root: classes.input}} id={id} />
    </span>
  );
  return injectSheet(styles)(InputField);
})();


// Demonstration
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <dl>
        <dt>Without Wrapper:</dt>
        <dd><TextInput /></dd>
        <dt>With Wrapper:</dt>
        <dd><InputField id="f" label="Foo"/></dd>
        <dt>What I want:</dt>
        <dd><InputField classes={{input: 'generated-by-TextInput-root generated-by-InputField-input'}} id="b" label="Foo"/></dd>
      </dl>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.generated-by-TextInput-root {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.generated-by-InputField-input {
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jss/9.8.7/jss.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-jss@8.6.1/dist/react-jss.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Instead of simply overriding the class name generated by the inner component, I want to apply that class, then the outer components custom styles on top of it. Essentially, I would like to make the `classes` prop work in an '*additive*' way.

Is there any way to do this gracefully?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something along the lines of the following:

```
...
const TextInput = ({ classes, classesFromParent, ...rest }) => (
    <input className={classes.root + ' ' + classesFromParent.root} type="text" {...rest} />
);
...
const InputField = ({ classes, id, label }) => (
    <span className={classes.root}>
      <label className={classes.label} htmlFor={id}>{label}</label>
      <TextInput classesFromParent={{root: classes.input}} id={id} />
    </span>
);
```

Comment: This works, but it really doesn't feel graceful at all. I'd have add a *lot* of checks to `classesFromParent` in almost every component (every one that uses `classes` anyway). Plus it makes for a pretty muddled API.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative way to approach the problem. Instead of trying to pass a class from the parent to be merged in with the child's classes, influence the child using the parent's styles (e.g. `'& > input': { width: 80 }`).

```js
const { Component } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM;
const injectSheet = reactJss.default;

// TextInput.jsx
const TextInput = (() => {
  const styles = {
    root: {
      border: '1px solid #ccc',
      borderRadius: 3,
    }
  };
  const TextInput = ({ classes, ...rest }) => (
    <input className={classes.root} type="text" {...rest} />
  );
  return injectSheet(styles)(TextInput);
})();

// InputField.jsx
const InputField = (() => {
  const styles = {
    root: {
      display: 'inline-flex',
      '& > input': {
        width: 80
      }
    },
    label: {
      marginRight: 5,
      width: 40,
    }
  };
  const InputField = ({ classes, id, label }) => (
    <span className={classes.root}>
      <label className={classes.label} htmlFor={id}>{label}</label>
      <TextInput id={id} />
    </span>
  );
  return injectSheet(styles)(InputField);
})();


// Demonstration
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <dl>
        <dt>Without Wrapper:</dt>
        <dd><TextInput /></dd>
        <dt>With Wrapper:</dt>
        <dd><InputField id="f" label="Foo"/></dd>
      </dl>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jss/9.8.7/jss.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-jss@8.6.1/dist/react-jss.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

We went for overriding behaviour. In some cases you want to add your class in some others you want to override them, but I don't think we can't have both at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Good to hear from one of the creators. Is there a way to use a plugin or custom HoC to get this to work? This functionality would be somewhat similar to the `jss-compose` plugin, but I'm not sure how it could be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to one of the other solutions, but more robust to work with additional classes. We can use `Object.values(classes).join(' ')` to join all the classes passed to to the `TextInput` component.

Note that I also had to give the class a different key. `classes={{root: classes.input}}` became `classes={{input: classes.input}}`.

```js
const { Component } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM;
const injectSheet = reactJss.default;

// TextInput.jsx
const TextInput = (() => {
  const styles = {
    root: {
      border: '1px solid #ccc',
      borderRadius: 3,
    }
  };
  const TextInput = ({ classes, ...rest }) => (
      <input className={Object.values(classes).join(' ')} type="text" {...rest} />
  );
  return injectSheet(styles)(TextInput);
})();

// InputField.jsx
const InputField = (() => {
  const styles = {
    root: {
      display: 'inline-flex',
    },
    label: {
      marginRight: 5,
      width: 40,
    },
    input: {
      width: 80,
    },
  };
  const InputField = ({ classes, id, label }) => (<span className={classes.root}>
      <label className={classes.label} htmlFor={id}>{label}</label>
      <TextInput classes={{input: classes.input}} id={id} />
    </span>
  );
  return injectSheet(styles)(InputField);
})();


// Demonstration
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <dl>
        <dt>Without Wrapper:</dt>
        <dd><TextInput /></dd>
        <dt>With Wrapper:</dt>
        <dd><InputField id="f" label="Foo"/></dd>
        <dt>What I want:</dt>
        <dd><InputField classes={{input: 'generated-by-TextInput-root generated-by-InputField-input'}} id="b" label="Foo"/></dd>
      </dl>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.generated-by-TextInput-root {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.generated-by-InputField-input {
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jss/9.8.7/jss.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-jss@8.6.1/dist/react-jss.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: IMO, this is cleaner that having a completely separate prop, but it breaks when I want different classes to apply to different child elements. Perhaps you can generate keys such as `input` and `_input` to be joined but not `label` and `_label` -- still thinking about how I could do that with a plugin/HoC.

Comment: Yeah, passing and combining class names probably isn't going to lead to an elegant solution, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an issue to investigate if we can/should add the merging behavior to react-jss https://github.com/cssinjs/jss/issues/933